# Traer un valor de un modelo a mi vista laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

Estoy enviando desde mi controlador `name,app,tlf,cel,fechadeingreso` todo esto va en mi variable `$clients`. En mi vista se muestra bien, ahora quiero calcular el tiempo que ha transcurrido desde le fecha que se ingreso ese cliente, para ello he creado la función:

```
public function actividad($query)
    {
        $diff = $query->diffForHumans(Carbon::now());
        return $this->where('actividad','=',$diff);
    }
```

en mi modelo `User` y intento traer la respuesta desde mi vista

```
<td>{{ $cliente->actividad->actividad }}</td>
```

pero me muestra este error

> Trying to get property of non-object (View:

¿cómo traer esa respuesta a mi vista?

Comment: ¿Estás llamando a una propiedad en la vista pero lo que quieres es llamar el método que definiste en el modelo `User`?

Comment: Exacto es lo que pretendo hacer

Comment: Porque no lo haces desde el contralador?

Comment: @Cidius no debería ser responsabilidad del controlador manipular información que viene de los modelos, aún así sería mucho mejor que lo que pretende hacer actualmente.

Comment: me referia con una suerte de scope

Comment: anteriormente realice esa función en el mismo controlador, pero no funcionó, porque al momento de pasar ese campo a la vista no tenía una sincronización con los demás registros, me mostraba fechas no acordes al usuario. por ese motivo lo mejor seria crear una funcion en el modelo para enviar un parametro desde la vista y retornar la fecha ya calculada el tiempo transcurrido.

Comment: Y la comparacion en la vista? en vez del modelo? supongo q actividad es un campo de cliente no?

Comment: Claro actividad es un campo del cliente en la vista intento llamarlo <td>{{ $cliente->actividad->actividad }}</td> y obtener la respuesta

Comment: y diff que contiene? la fecha actual?

Answer (score 1):

Sin entender muy bien porque deseas llamar un método que parece ser un subquery, lo podrías hacer fácilmente en el controlador, asumiendo que no tengas otra capa a la cual le estés delegando esta clase de tareas.

Me baso en esta frase de la pregunta:

> quiero calcular el tiempo que ha transcurrido desde le fecha que se ingreso ese cliente

También dices que ya tienes una propiedad `fechadeingreso` en `$cliente`.

Yo intentaría algo así en el controlador:

```
$fechaIngreso = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($cliente->fechadeingreso);

$tiempoTranscurrido = $fechaIngreso->diffForHumans();
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas intentando acceder a un metodo de una propiedad, y no del modelo.

Prueba así:

```
public function actividad()
    {

        $diff = Carbon::now()->diffForHumans(Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$this->fechadeingreso));

        /*Cambiar Y-m-d por el formato que tengas*/

        return $diff;
    }
```

En la vista:

```
<td>{{ $cliente->actividad() }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Funciona bien amigo, tuve que cambiar mi consulta de esto 
**/*$clients = \DB::table('users')
                ->join('clients', 'users.id', '=', 'clients.users_id')              ->join('provinces','clients.provincia_idprovincia','=','provinces.id')
                ->where('users.is_admin', '=', '0')
                ->select('users.status','users.id','users.actividad', 'clients.name','clients.apellidos','clients.dir1','clients.dir2','clients.telefono','clients.path','clients.celular','clients.email','provinces.prov')
                ->paginate(10);*/**
a
**$clients = User::select('users.status','users.id','users.actividad as fechadeingreso', 'clients.name','clients.apellidos','clients.dir1','clients.dir2','clients.telefono','clients.path','clients.celular','clients.email','provinces.prov')
                ->join('clients','users.id', '=', 'clients.users_id')
                ->join('provinces','clients.provincia_idprovincia','=','provinces.id')
                ->where('users.is_admin', '=', '0')
                ->get();**
para poder obtener un valor del modelo, en mi vista le agregue 
**{{ $cliente->actividad() }}** 
y en mi modelo 
**public function actividad()
    {
        $diff = Carbon::now()->diffForHumans(Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$this->fechadeingreso));
        /*Cambiar Y-m-d por el formato que tengas*/
        return $diff;
    }** 
y funciona todo al pelo gracias a todos por el apoyo